# Django models choices - allow only specific transitions on the admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

for a models.IntegerField I can define easily choices with

```
sth = models.IntegerField(choices=(
    (1, 'sth1'),
    (2, 'sth2'),
    (3, 'sth3'),
))
```

. Is there any way where I can restrict the transitions from one value to another one?

For instance if the current value is '1', it can go only to '2', but if the current value is '3', it can go to '1' and '2', etc.

I need this restriction only on the admin interface. Is there anything built in for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Implement this in the form that is used by the modeladmin.

Comment: I need this on the object view (change) page, not on the list page. What can be my entry point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a subclass of the `ModelForm` to encode this logic:

```
STH_TRANSITIONS = {
    1: [2],
    2: [3],
    3: [1, 2]
}

class FSMModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        sth = self.fields['sth']
        trans = STH_TRANSITIONS.get(self.instance.sth)
        if trans is not None:
            sth.choices = [
                (k, v) for k, v in sth.choices
                if k == self.instance.sth or k in trans
            ]
```

Then you plug this in into the `ModelAdmin` of that model:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = FSMModelForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to implement a Finite State Machine. Something you can try is to use [django-fsm](https://github.com/viewflow/django-fsm) together with [django-fsm-admin](https://github.com/gadventures/django-fsm-admin). Those two packages allow you to specify from which state a transition is allowed into another state.